# How to disable StrictHostKeyChecking in Plink? (Using plink so I can specify password)

Tags: ssh, putty, plink

Yes, I know, it's insecure: I will be using this for my personal Raspberry Pi, on my personal computer, on my home wifi, and I will have nothing important on there.

I'm just making a profile in the Windows Terminal Preview that automatically SSHs into the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to know (but others might not), verifying host key fingerprint is an integral part of securing your connection. Blindly accepting any host key will make you vulnerable to the [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

---

For this reason, PuTTY tools do not have any equivalent of `StrictHostKeyChecking=no`.

Instead, use the [`-hostkey` switch](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-hostkey) to provide the fingerprint of the expected/known host key.

```
plink.exe username@example.com -pw password -hostkey xx:xx:xx:xx... command
```